# Erro ao obter valor do input file via jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Galera, estou tendo dificuldades ao tentar obter o valor do `input` do tipo `file` via jQuery. Basicamente, selecionei o `input` atribui a ele um evento `.click()`, depois disso tento obter o valor do `input`, mas na realidade nem abrir a janela para seleção do arquivo abre.

**JS**

```
$(function(){

nome_img = $('#nome_img');
complemento_img = $('#complemento_img');

nome_img.text("Sem imagem");
complemento_img.text("Clique aqui para selecionar uma imagem");

$('#areaupload').click(function () {

    $('#foto').click(function () {

        var arquivo = $(this).val();

        if ( arquivo != " ") {

            nome_img.text(arquivo);
            complemento_img.text("Arquivo selecionado");
        }
        else
        {
            //
        }

    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Nova Notícia</title>
    <!-- CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/skin-light.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/easyeditor.css">
    <!-- FONT -->
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <!-- JS -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.easyeditor.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {

            new EasyEditor('#editor');

            nome_img = $('#nome_img');
            complemento_img = $('#complemento_img');

            nome_img.text("Sem imagem");
            complemento_img.text("Clique aqui para selecionar uma imagem");

            $('#areaupload').click(function () {

                $('#foto').click(function () {

                    var arquivo = $(this).val();

                    if ( arquivo != " ") {

                        nome_img.text(arquivo);
                        complemento_img.text("Arquivo selecionado");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //
                    }

                });

            });

            $("#publicar > a").click(function (e) {

                e.preventDefault();

                var titulo  = $('#titulo');
                var noticia = $('#noticia');

                if ( (titulo == "") || (noticia == "") ) {

                    alert('Por favor, todos os campos devem ser preenchidos.');

                    return false;
                }

            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrap clearfix">
        <!-- row -->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="window" style="margin-top: 7.0em; width: 70% !important;">
                <div class="slice" style="padding: 20px 9px;">
                    Criar notícia
                </div>
                <!-- Editor -->
                    <div id="editor">

                    </div>
                <!-- Fim editor -->
                <!-- Upload -->
                <div id="upload">
                    <div id="areaupload">
                        <section id="nome_img"></section>
                        <section id="complemento_img"></section>
                    </div>
                    <input type="file" id="foto">
                </div>
                <!-- Fim upload -->
                <div class="buttons clearfix">
                    <div class="button_line" id="publicar">
                        <a href="">Publicar</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="button_line" id="limpar">
                        Limpar
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- fim da row -->
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: você pode colocar o HTML também? mas de antemao, não me parece logico colocar o `$('#foto').click()` dentro do `$('#areaupload').click()`.

Comment: Bem, a questão é que, por questões estéticas, resolvi dexar o input invisível e ao clicar em  `#areaupload` ele simula o clique em `#foto` que é o id do input